# Auto-close or overwrite browser tabs opened thru command line

Tags: javascript

I have a shell script producing a html page. It then opens it in a webbrowser, using the simple syntax

```
opera result.html
```

However, if I run this script several times, I get as many tabs/windows as runs. I tried to load another page containing a script that opens 'result.html' into a definite target-window, but this script page will not close using window.close() or self.close() [presumably because it was not opened by a javascript...], so it's the script page that is repeated...

Is there a way, either to have a webbrowser open a file into a target using the commandline, or to auto-close a window that was opened thru command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which platform are you using? For Unix, there is an `-activetab` switch you can use.

```
opera -activetab result.html
```

See [Opera's Command Line Options](http://www.opera.com/docs/switches/) page for different platform switches that may be suitable.

Comment: Thanks, this does suit the application, and I do use Unix. I notice this seems to be specific to opera, firefox seems to have only new-tab or new-window options.

Comment: @Joce: Yes, command line switches aren't consistent and differ from browser to browser. You can usually find a list of them online though.